# server for unattended Windows and Linux installations

Tags: linux, windows, installation, unattended

what kind of software can handle with such problem: i need to prepare PC's for new employees in office, but I'm not administrator. I'd like to automate process of installing operating systems (Windows 7 and Ubuntu) and necessary software for new developers and other roles. We have standard pc/laptops configurations. I thought if I could to prepare one machine, then take an image of system and then deploy it via network to provide fast deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a tool already exists that does this but I wasn't able to find one. What I've done in the past is use a pre-installation disk like BartPE (http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) alone with Ghost. This let me create images of the most common OS setups and installs once and then just ghost the appropriate image on to the machine within minutes.

If you are looking to automate it for Windows you should check out System Centre Operations Manager or Cobbler for Linux systems that will let you push out OS's over the network using PXE

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2010 it is free and it is the official tool for deploying Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Explore for **G4U**. It will clone whole PC from source image to client machine.